# Set Offset is jQuery's Toggle Slide

Tags: jquery

```
$('.shutter').bind("click", function () {
    $(".expander").slideToggle("800", "easeOutCubic");
});
```

but if I do not want the expander's `height= 0;`

If I want the `height = 20px` (offset) after applying slide up, so my question is that, is there any possible way to set Offset in toggleSlide method or any alternate? Like:

```
$('.shutter').bind("click", function () {
    $(".expander").slideToggle{20, ("800", "easeOutCubic")};
});
```

I know above example is not the correct one, but it just an example to show you what I want..

Answer (score 1):

For applying `height: 20px;` after the `slideToggle`, add a callback:

```
$('.shutter').bind("click", function() {
        $(".expander").slideToggle("800", "easeOutCubic", function() {
            $(this).css({'height':'20px'});
    });
});
```

UPDATE: After comments, you have used the `easeOutCubic` improperly, instead use it like:

```
$('.shutter').bind('click', function() {
    if($('.expander').attr('style') == 'height: 20px;') {
        $('.expander').animate({'height':'200px'}, 800);
    } else {
       $('.expander').animate({'height':'20px'}, 800);
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/1748/)

Comment: What's not working? This will apply the css style of height: 20px after the slide toggle has finished. If this is not what you wanted, please rephrase your question to make it clearer.

Comment: That's not working the way you thinking, not setting the height after it slides, if you still think it should work then Provide JsFiddle example

Comment: @Faizan If I understand correctly, you may want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hN9m3/2/ ?

Comment: @Enijar Your code make work for once only, here i want toggle it Several times, if default height of 'expander' is 500px, and i click toggle it should become 20px, then if i click toggle again it must extent to its default height not 20px

Answer (score 0):

You could animate the height instead of using `slideToggle()` method:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/1747/)

```
 $('.shutter').bind('click', function () {
     var $expander = $('.expander');
     $expander.finish().animate({
         height: $expander.height() === 200?20:200
     }, '800',"easeOutCubic");
 });
```